# Promise not returning the data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Iam trying to get the data based on ObjectId using promises. It is fetching the data from DB , but not returning the result . The following is my code

```
getScreenDetails = function(req, res) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    screen.find({
        "_id": req.params.id
      })
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      }, (err) => {
        reject({ status: "failure", error: err });
      })
  });
};
```

Any suggestion would be Appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. Please describe exactly what isn't working.

Comment: It *looks* like it is returning the result, but you haven't shown us how you are calling the function, how you are trying to look at the result, what output you get, or what output you expect.

Comment: How are you calling that `getScreenDetails()` method?

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why you are wrapping all that in a promise instead of just returning `screen.find()` … which will return a promise anyway.

Comment: It is not resolving the promise . from here ( resolve(response);) iam not getting any data in postman

Comment: Iam exporting router.get('/getScreenDetails/:id', getScreenDetails); it @AJC24

Comment: @ShaikNizamuddin — Why would you get data in Postman? There's no sign of you taking the data from the promise and sending it in an HTTP response.

Comment: your problem relies with the router/server then - which I guess is express - you probably just need to send the response using res.send(...) on your `then` callback

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the promise is not finishing. The problem is that you need to end the request explicitly. I also don't know why you create a promise. Try something like this:

```
getScreenDetails = function(req, res) {
  find({
    "_id": req.params.id
  }).then((response) => {
    res.send(response);
  })
};
```

If you are using Express, check this out: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion